# Change docker login credentials on Rancher

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

In my [Rancher](https://rancher.com/) dashboard, I'm getting these error messages: "Failed to pull image" and "ImagePullBackoff" when I try to deploy from a docker image. It appears linked to a recent change of Docker Hub login credentials. However, I can't find a way to change the credentials in Rancher. I thought this would be as easy as specifying the new password "somewhere", but I can't seem to find that "somewhere" in the Rancher dashboard. So my question is how can I change the docker login credentials that Rancher is using to pull my image for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I think [these are the instructions](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/k8s-in-rancher/registries/) you're asking about?  I went through them in my Rancher setup and they worked out fine.

[image]